# Binding List<List<String>> to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am wondering how to bind a `List<List<String>>` to the columns of a DataGrid in WPF. Say I have the following code:

```
List<List<string>> ugly = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> u0 = new List<string>{"one", "two", "three", "four"};
List<string> u1 = new List<string> { "five", "six", "seven", "eight" };
List<string> u2 = new List<string> { "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve" };
ugly.Add(u0);
ugly.Add(u1);
ugly.Add(u2);
```

If I set the ItemsSource of the datagrid (called `dataGrid`) to one of the `List<string>`, then a column is filled with the appropriate data. For example, `dataGrid.ItemsSource = u0` results in the following:

[image]

How do I make it so that there is a column for each `List<String>` in `ugly`?

Comment: Create a custom class.

Comment: You may not understand how grid works, each item in your datasource list should correspond to 1 row in your grid. That means each `List<string>` in your ugly will correspond to 1 row, the columns will correspond to properties of each item, the only properties you have in your `List<string>` are `Count` and `Capacity`. So looks like you are stuck. You have to convert your `ugly` to something your grid can consume.

Comment: you have several options depending on your purpose, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812020/how-to-bind-an-2d-array-bool-to-a-wpf-datagrid-one-way other option might be to define a wrapPanel containing one datagrid for each column and link their vertical scrollbar offset to each other using their events.

Comment: @KingKing Is there a way to make datagrid column properties correspond to an index in a list? To clarify, if I still want to have a List<string> in the data structure, is there a way to have the first column correspond to the list item at index 0, the second column correspond to the list item at index 1, etc? I ask because I don't know how many strings there will be, so making dedicated properties in the data structure for each is impossible.

Comment: @masturcheef I'm afraid that's not easy, because the number of items is dynamic while as I said, columns correspond to **Properties**, you have to define or somehow create the properties dynamically for each item in your list, as far as I know that's deadly hard and maybe impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many items are in the outer collection then you can copy the inner `List<string>` collections into an anonymous type before you display them. .. using your example:

```
var item = new { Column1 = u0, Column2 = u1, Column3 = u2 };
YourDataGrid.ItemsSource = item;
```

You can find out more from my answer to the [WPF : Dynamically create a grid with specified x rows and y columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115742/wpf-dynamically-create-a-grid-with-specified-x-rows-and-y-columns/20116960#20116960) question here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`Column` in dataGrid corresponds to a `property` in underlying DataItem collection. You can do that by using array of anonymous type containing three properties in it.

Also make sure dataGrid `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to `true`.

```
dg.ItemsSource = new[] { new { First = u0[0], Second = u1[0], Third = u2[0] },
                         new { First = u0[1], Second = u1[1], Third = u2[1] },
                         new { First = u0[2], Second = u1[2], Third = u2[2] },
                         new { First = u0[3], Second = u1[3], Third = u2[3] }};
```