# Dynamic table in universal app

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, win-universal-app, stackpanel

I am developing universal app for windows phone 8.1/windows 8.1. I am using MVVM pattern. I have table with dynamic number of stackpanels that are bind to source in view model. One stackpanel is one row in the table. How can I make items in stack panels same width? I know about `IsSharedSizeScope`, but this is not available in grids in universal app.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding PowerMaxiTableSource0, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border Background="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text0}" />
                </Border>
                <Border Background="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1}" />
                </Border>
                <Border Background="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2}" />
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Because this is table I tried using grid instead of stackpanels, but I couldn't make it work. I tried this solution [wpf grid with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814224/wpf-grid-with-dynamic-columns). But I ended up with items clustered in row 0, column 0 even with correct values in bind properties.

Any help would be much appreciated (even solution with grid).

Comment: Would it be possible to give all of the TextBlocks a fixed width and use the TextTrimming property?

Comment: Well it would be better without fixed width as I need to cover many different screen sizes, but I don't see any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StackPanel`s width is driven by its children. It looks like there are 3 children in the `StackPanel`, meaning they are not dynamically generated. You state that only the number of stack  panels changes. If you are not opposed to the `Grid` use instead of your `StackPanel`, than the following code will work because the `Grid` will automatically will stretch (take all allowable width) and trickle down that width to it's children dynamically if you create columns who's width is specified as percentage:

```
<ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text0}" />
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1}" />
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2}" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank it works nearly perfect. However the width is off in some cells sometimes, but that is acceptable in my situation, thank you.